# rule out a url from my proxy configuration on unity

Tags: proxy

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and it is running just fine. I only have a problem, I connect to the internet through a proxy at my college, but there are some url's that I don't need the proxy for, so my question is: How can I exempt a url from my proxy configuration on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You may need a proxy configuration script (PAC). It is a universal solution, and works in any DE, any platform, with any browser.

In your proxy settings, either in browser, or from `Network` in Unity, select 'Automatic proxy configuration URL' and type in a path like `/home/<Your-user-name>/proxy` or some other convinient path.

Open a text editor, ( Search in Dash to find gedit -the default text editor) and write something like this. Save it to the path entered above, when done. Modify to your needs.

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
// Loopback and localhost goes browser direct always.
    var reip;
    if ((host == "localhost") ||
           (shExpMatch(host, "localhost.*")) ||
           (shExpMatch(host,"10.*")) ||
           (shExpMatch(host,"172.16.*")) || 
           (shExpMatch(host,"192.168.*")) ||
           (shExpMatch(host,"144.16.128.*")) ||
           (host == "127.0.0.1")) {
        return "DIRECT";
    } 
// Local Sites
    if (dnsDomainIs(host, ".example.com") ||
       dnsDomainIs(host, ".qwerty.org")) {
        return "DIRECT";
    }
// Test to see if host is an IP address
// Put any ranges you want to skip proxy here.
    reip = /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/g;
    if (reip.test(host)) {
        if (isInNet(host, "10.0.0.0", "255.0.0.0") ||
            isInNet(host, "172.16.0.0", "255.255.0.0") ||
            isInNet(host, "144.16.128.0", "255.255.240.0") ||
            isInNet(host,"192.168.0.0", "255.255.0.0")) {
             return "DIRECT";
        }
    }
// Default to proxy.
    return "PROXY <server>:<port>";
}
```

As you see, complex configurations can be made out of PAC scripts. The above script skips proxy for any address of type *.example.com and *.qwerty.org and any ip that matches the ranges. All other requests are routed through proxy server.

P.S: I've seen a empty line at top and bottom in all PAC scripts I've seen so far, so I suggest you add a newline both at top and mottom. Just in case...

Comment: Additional info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using an http proxy you can open gconf-editor (`sudo apt-get install gconf-editor`, if you don't have it already) navigate to `system:http_proxy` and add the urls you want to exempt into the `ignore_hosts` key, separated by commas I believe. (see picture below)

[image: ignore_hosts key]

If you are using a socks5 proxy it's a little more complicated to set system wide.  However for certain individual programs it's quite easy.  For Firefox for example, go to `edit:preferences:advanced:(connection)settings` then change it from `Use system proxy settings` or whatever it is to `Manual proxy configuration`, then enter your proxy information and add the urls you don't want in the `No proxy for` field, once again separated by commas. (See screenshot below)

[image: no_proxy_for setting]

If you use Chromium you can run it with command line switches, for example `/etc/bin/chromium-browser --proxy-bypass-list="localhost,127.0.0.1,xxx.xxx.xx.etc" --proxy-server="socks5://localhost:1080"`.

Some other applications will have similar functionality, and you can use a wrapper program like `tsocks` for those that don't.